# crosswalk cordova android update project?

Tags: android, cordova, ant

how to solve? i am using Migrate an existing Cordova application to Crosswalk   this command

```
android update project --subprojects --path . \
        --target "android-19"
```

Show  this error:

```
 build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
```

Comment: Is this actually related to that line? This message is usually spit out (or at least that is what I have noticed.)

Which version of cordova and crosswalk are you using?  If you are using the latest stable -- based on chromium 40, you will need to update cordova to use the newest cli from npm (4.3) and use the target `android-21` while building the crosswalk library.

Answer (score 1):

Always use android version 21 and you will be just fine...also I've got issues on stable releases, try beta ones...and pick the right crosswalk instance (for me it was the Cordova Android (ARM) one)

Comment: I'm able to get Crosswalk and my Android project to build with 21, but I can't get it to run on a 4.1+ device. I try to update Android to 19 and then my Android project fails to build. I'm not attempting to rebuild the Crosswalk libraries. Am I missing a step?

Comment: which one of the libraries are you using?

Comment: try to use this one https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/beta/12.41.296.4/arm/crosswalk-cordova-12.41.296.4-arm.zip